# Can i get the total number of files,folders & size for a sharepoint online document library

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, pnp-powershell, list-view-threshold, pnp

Inside sharepoint (on-prem & on-line) we can get the total number of items inside a document library (this includes files and folders) from the site content page.
but i have a document library with around 28,000 items, and i want to know the following info:-

1. Total number of files.
2. Total number of folders/sub-folders
3. total size.
4. number of files for certain types (.docx, pdf, etc)..

now i try to run the "Generate file plan report" for the document library, but i got this error `The attempted operation is prohibited because it exceeds the list view threshold enforced by the administrator.`, since my DL contain more than 5,000 items . so can i get the info i need using PnP?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop all items of the library and use IF condition to classify different types files and folders then count them.
[Powershell script to get count of how many files are in a folder and its subfolders](https://collab365.community/forum/topics/powershell-script-to-get-count-of-how-many-files-are-in-a-folder/)